# Why is g++ returning a 'Segmentation fault' error when I point a node to a char of data?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, declaration

I have a program that returns an error after I've compiled, then run it in g++. I know because when I test this code in Visual Studio that this error is occuring when I try to set a new nodes data pointer equal to something. More specifically, when I try to set `n->data = ch;` Visual Studio breaks (stops) at that line of code. For context, here's part of my header file (with `n->data = ch;` towards the end):

```
#include <ostream>

class LinkedList
{
public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();

        void add(char ch);
private:
    struct node
    {
            node();
            char data;
            node * next;
    };
    node * head;
    node * curr;
    node * prev;
};
LinkedList::LinkedList() : head(nullptr), curr(nullptr), prev(nullptr);
LinkedList::node::node() : data('\0'), next(nullptr);
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    if (!head) // head is null and so list is empty
    {
            return; //nothing to delete
    }

    for(curr = head; head; /* head isn't NULL*/ delete curr /*delete first element*/)
    {
            curr = head;  // set curr to head of list
            head = curr->next;  // move head over to next element (or make it null)
    }
}
void LinkedList::add(char ch)
{
    node * n = nullptr;
    n->next = nullptr; //my compiler doesn't like this
    n->data = ch; // or this
    //irrelevant code after this.
}
```

I wish I could give you guys more context, but I'm clueless as to why this isn't working. Even if it *does* have something to do with C strings, I don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: The compiler does not throw errors.

Comment: You probably want to replace `node * n = nullptr;` with `node * n = new node;` (and store `n` somewhere)

Comment: Odds are n doesn't point to anything valid.

Comment: You have to make a pointer actually point to something before you dereference it.

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what you mean by "My compiler is throwing an error when I try to set a new nodes data pointer equal to something." and "the compiler freaks". Do you really mean that *compilation* fails? Or do you mean that it compiles, but doesn't behave as you expect when you run the result?

Comment: @Jon Skeet It compiles but doesn't behave as I expect.

Comment: Then it's *not* the "compiler throwing an error" or "the compiler freaking". It's important to be precise with your descriptions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sorry, it compiles in g++, but not Visual Studio.

Comment: So what happens in Visual Studio? All of this should have been in the question, right from the very start...

Comment: @Jon Skeet It breaks at that line of code, which is how I knew that was what was causing the error. I didn't really think that that was important.

Comment: "it breaks" again doesn't describe what you're seeing. How can "what goes wrong" not be important? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> void LinkedList::add(char ch)
> {
>     node * n = nullptr; // ##
>     n->next = nullptr; //my compiler doesn't like this
>     n->data = ch; // or this
>
>     ...
> ```

In the first line (marked as `##`), you define a pointer to a `node`, and initialize it to `nullptr`, so the pointer actually points to *"nothing"*.

As a consequence of that, you cannot set values for the `node` data structure fields (`n->next` and `n->data`) using that pointer, since it's pointing to nothing as per previous line.

What you could do to fix that is to create an instance of a new `node` (for example using **`new`**), and then prepare the fields of that instance, using `n->next` and `n->data`.

Comment: I would need to delete n at the end of that function then, right?

Comment: @LarryK: Actually, if you are implemented a linked-list class, you may want to chain the newly created node to the remaining part of the list. The right place to delete the list's nodes is in the **destructor** (`~LinkedList`).

Comment: Is my deconstructor now, sufficient? Should I change it if I don't want a memory leak?

Comment: @LarryK: I'm sorry I don't have the bandwidth right now to double-check your destructor code. You may want to debug it by yourself, to check if it properly releases every node. However, at a first glance, it seems correct.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to make sure that there weren't any major errors with my debugger.

Answer (score 2):

As your code

```
node * n = nullptr;
```

says assign null pointer to `n` then you dereferencing that null pointer by

```
 n->next = nullptr;
```

So, it cause Segmentation fault.

To solve use

```
node * n = new node();
n->next = nullptr;
n->data = ch;
```

Comment: @NathanOliver, actually he said '//irrelevant code after this.', so we may assume he might done that things.